# How Can i Resize a UIImage By Pressing a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Like what code should i use so i can press a button while i use my app so it will resize my UIImage to my desired size

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with Interface Builder, outlets and actions, etc.? Have you read the UIImageView class reference?

Comment: im familiar with interface builder, outlets and actions, but i dont think i've read the uiimageview class reference

Answer (score 0):

Modify your UIImageView bounds or frame property inside the callback method connected to your button. Like so:

```
-(void) buttonWasPressed{
myView.frame = CGRectMake( x_origin, y_origin, width, height);
}
```

Comment: what do i put in between -(void) and {   ?

Comment: Any name you want. You probably need to use an IBAction so you can hook it up to your button inside interface builder.

Comment: And I would hook it up by giving it the name of my ibaction?